# Differentiability of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, derivatives

Trivial question but I am confused with the notation

If $p_{n-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, is it   $\in$ the differentiability class  C^n$?

Obviously if $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then it is in $C^n$   as it is continuous as well as having its first $n$ derivatives continuous.

Comment: Can you formulate the question more clearly? Each polynomial is in $C^k$ for any $k$, because *all* derivatives are continuous.

Comment: Every polynomial is in $C^\infty$.

Comment: Every polynomial is in $C^{\omega}({\mathbb R})$ $(=$ analytic functions on ${\mathbb R}).$